# List wifi networks when wifi is in AP mode and also when it is in station mode

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, networkmanager

For my embedded system, I need quite versatile network management. I need to be able to use wifi in `AP` and `station` mode and switch between them. I'm using `NetworkManager` for this.

But i have found, that `nmcli` can't list wifi networks, when wifi is in `AP mode`. I know, that `iw` can list networks in `AP mode`, which could be solution, but when I try to list networks in `station mode`, `iw` hangs. I could detect, if I'm in `AP` or `station` mode and select one or the other tool, but this seems quite dodgy for me.

Isn't here any better solution?

Comment: Please explain your setup.

Comment: @harrymc, I'm using raspberry pi 4 with custom build yocto image. I have disabled internal wifi and I'm using WN821N for wireless connection. I'm using NetworkManager for networking devices management.

Comment: Do you really want your AP going off-channel to scan? 802.11 kind of assumes the AP is always on-channel. Last time I checked there was no good way for an AP to tell its clients to stand by because it's going away for a bit. I recommend you do your scans from a separate WNIC.